# Github update local repository

Tags: git, github

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I have a code on GitHub cloned on 2 separate computers. When I make changes to the code, I would sync it with the server.

However, I don't know the proper way to 're-clone' the code from github to the other computer. I would always re-delete the entire solution before cloning it again. Is there a proper way to update the local repository with the code from GitHub ? Help thanks

Comment: Something like `git fetch/git pull` ?

Comment: You want to re-clone the repo entirely? Why not just update with `git pull`?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the use of git on the command line I suggest to try https://desktop.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

Read https://git-scm.com/documentation for basic usage & workflow of git.

### For your question:

- 1. push code from computer A -> github
- 2. pull code from github to computer B

### **Conflict:**

And if you modify from both computer, then there might be conflicts.

In that case, before push to github, do a pull first, then resolve the conflict locally, if any, then push.